# AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpresponse, scrape

Hi i get the above error. Why does it pop up, what am I missing and how do I get around it ? Thanks

```
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

from html2text import html2text

sock = html2text(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')) 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
print (htmlSource)
```

Im running IDLE 3.4.3 on a Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Now Im getting :TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Answer (score 2):

`html2text` expects the HTML code passed in *as a string* - read the response:

```
source = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com').read()
text = html2text(source)
print(text)
```

It prints:

```
# Example Domain

This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents.
You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for
permission.

[More information...](http://www.iana.org/domains/example)
```

Comment: @user3115713 please go through this and the previous questions you've asked and see if there are answers that need to or should be accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution for Python 3.4. I just decoded source into UTF-8 and it worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

from html2text import html2text

source=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com').read() 
s=html2text(source.decode("UTF-8"))

print (s)
```

Output

```
# Example Domain

This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents.
You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for
permission.

[More information...](http://www.iana.org/domains/example)
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. I had figured python 3.x seem to have a little world of their own. For the solution why did it have to be decoded to utf-8 and how did you arrive to take such an approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace is an attribute for strings and you have a fileobject

```
obj=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
print obj
```

.

```
<addinfourl at 3066852812L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xb6d267ec>>
```

This one is OK.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

from html2text import html2text


source=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com').read() 
s=html2text(source)

print s
```

Output

```
This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents.
You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for
permission.

[More information...](http://www.iana.org/domains/example
```

Comment: still getting a data = data.replace("</' + 'script>", "</ignore>") "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Comment: That's weird. I don't.

Comment: What version of python are you using as Im running a 3.x with  IDLE on a windows 7 OS. ?

Comment: Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. And yes, I tried this script with Python 3.4, it gave an error "data = data.replace("</' + 'script>", "</ignore>") TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object". I think html2text  module is not compatible with Python 3.4. "print (source)" works OK, it just fails to produce any text out of html. Weird.